# CrudRepository wrong select query

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tests")
public class Test implements Serializable {

@Column(nullable = false)
private String prop1;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String prop2;

@Id
@Column(nullable = false)
private String prop3;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String prop4;

public Test(final String prop1, final String prop2, final String prop3, final String prop4) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2 = prop2;
    this.prop3 = prop3;
    this.prop4 = prop4;
}
```

I have created the following interface that extends `CrudRepository`

```
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<Test, String> {
    // blank
}
```

In my controller I have the following code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

@Autowired
private TestRepository testRepository;

@RequestMapping(method = GET)
@ResponseBody
public Iterable<Test> fetchTests() {
    return testRepository.findAll();
}
```

The problem is that when the `fetchTests` method is ran the query that is generated is something like:

```
select test0_.prop1 as prop11_0_, test0_.prop2 as prop22_0_, test0_.prop3 as prop33_0_, test0_.prop4 as prop44_0_ from tests test0_
```

whilst it should just be

```
select tests.prop1 as prop11_0_, tests.prop2 as prop22_0_, tests.prop3 as prop33_0_, tests.prop4 as prop44_0_ from tests
```

I can't understand where the extra `tests0_` reference comes from? Any ideas on what is wrong? I'm using postgre as dbms.

Comment: "test0_" is an ALIAS for the table "tests". A common enough feature in SQL.

Comment: it gives me an error when I run the same query using pgAdmin - could it be something postgresql specific? - it doesn't seem like an alias has been made

Comment: Show us the error then.

Comment: could the error be a secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test0_` from from the end of the select query, where it says: `from tests test0_`. It more or less gives your table an alias too. This looks fine IMHO.

Comment: it gives me an error when I run the same query using pgAdmin - could it be something postgresql specific? - it doesn't seem like an alias has been made

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out myself - sorry about the wasted time. Apparently, the naming convention for columns in postgre is to use snake_case whilst I was using camelCase. That seems to be the default naming convention in JPA as well (which I suppressed by setting a different naming strategy in the application.properties file).

The issue with the query was not with the test0_ reference which was correct as pointed by the other answers, but with selecting the camelCase columns in the db. After renaming the columns to use snake_case the issue is solved.

Comment: FWIW think you mean lowercase. PostgreSQL does not insert "_" between words. You define the table/column names and it simply respects UPPER, lower or Mixed case (UPPER and Mixed when quoted in PostgreSQL)